# Can't fix IntentService for notification with AlarmManager

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, android-broadcastreceiver, android-intentservice

I am trying to handle it this way: in `BroadcastReceiver` start `AlarmManager` repeated action, it will send intents to `IntentService`, service writes log. Now as I see from the log, `BroadcastReceiver` receives intent, starts `AlarmManager`, but `IntentService` never fires. What can be wrong here?

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".wakefullBroadcastReciever.SimpleWakefulReciever" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="START"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".wakefulService.NotificationWakefulIntentService"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="NOTIFY_INTENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

WakefulReciever:

```
public class SimpleWakefulReciever extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (!App.isRunning) {
            Log.d("wakefull", "start");
            Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationWakefulIntentService.class);
            startIntent.setAction(Utils.NOTIFY_INTENT);
            PendingIntent startPIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, startIntent, 0);
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 3000, 5000, startPIntent);
            App.isRunning = true;
        }
    }
}
```

IntentService:

```
public class NotificationWakefulIntentService extends IntentService {

    public NotificationWakefulIntentService() {
        super("NotificationWakefulIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("time",(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000)+"");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining an explicit `Service` `Intent`, but calling `getBroadcast()` instead of `getService()`.

Change the following:

```
PendingIntent startPIntent = PendingIntent
    .getBroadcast(context, 0, startIntent, 0);
```

To this:

```
PendingIntent startPIntent = PendingIntent
    .getService(context, 0, startIntent, 0);
```

Also, this is not how `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` works. It's a helper class and its purpose is to provide a `WakeLock` until your `Service` finishes its work.

You achieve nothing by simply extending `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, a `WakeLock` is guaranteed during `onReceive()` anyway.

To answer your comment below:

You should set an exact alarm to fire every hour (check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39739886/3363481)), start your `IntentService` from `onReceive()` by calling `WakefulBroadcastReceiver.startWakefulService()`, do your stuff in `onHandleIntent()` and call `WakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent()` when finished.