# Android Alarm Manager setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() not working in Android 7.0 Nougat in Doze mode

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alarms, android-7.0-nougat, android-doze

I am trying to make an alarm fire in my app every 30 minutes using Alarm Manager's `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` but it is not working!

I test the functionality by issuing a push notification whenever I receive an alarm signal.

The problem is: when the device enters doze mode after being idle for sometime, I no longer receive alarms. However, as soon as I turn On the screen, I receive a notification. My app needs accurate alarms that need to be delivered exactly on-time every 30 minutes! It can not afford to receive delayed alarms or dropped ones because the device is in Doze mode!

**I used the following in my code:**

1. I set the alarm when I open my app.
2. I receive the alarm signal using a WakefulBroadcastReceiver. In its 
   `onReceive()` method I set the next alarm. I also, start a 
    startWakefulService that only issues a push notification, then stops 
    itself.
3. I call completeWakefulIntent at the end of the onReceive().
4. I tried testing both: RTC_WAKEUP & ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP

**Notes:**

- The wakefulbroadcastReceiver class is registered in the Manifest.
- I added permissions for : `android.permission.WAKE_LOCK`
- I tried White-Listing my app, but the results are the same
- I tried using `setAlarmClock()` which worked all the time even during doze 
  mode, with one dropped/delayed alarm every 50 alarms. So, it is also not 
  perfect. And I don't want the user to see an alarm icon all the time up 
  there.
- Not only does setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() not work during doze, but also it 
  has terrible accuracy when it is working. I usually get lots of alarm signals
  either 1-3 minutes later or 1-3 minutes earlier.
- I am testing using Huawei Mate 8, and android 7.0 Nougat.

**P.S:** 
Before answering please make sure you are aware of the restrictions imposed starting Android 6.0 M and Doze mode.

Link1: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

In summary it says this:

- If you need to set alarms that fire while in Doze, use
  setAndAllowWhileIdle() or setExactAndAllowWhileIdle().
- Alarms set with setAlarmClock() continue to fire normally — the
  system exits Doze shortly before those alarms fire.

Now, why don't I get accurate alarm signals every 30 minutes using `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()`?!
And, why isn't `setAlarmClock()` 100% reliable?!

Comment: It might [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39739886/3117966)

Comment: I am having the same issue, and seeing similar observations. I wish someone from Google can step up to the plate and fix this issue.

Comment: @Mena
Did you find solution for this, I have the same issue.

Comment: @caucukien Still no solution....

Comment: @Mena did you find any solution?

Comment: @ZohabAli I gave up on this issue. I searched hundreds of forums, tried lots of combination of solutions together, and ran testing for days. Yet, I found no way to fix this problem.

Comment: I guess you can find the answer [hire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55540823/android-notifications-triggered-by-alarm-manager-not-firing-when-app-is-in-doze/55664818#55664818)

Answer (score 6):

You might get accurate alarms, but [in Doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html)

> The system ignores wake locks.

So it seems as though [`AlarmManager.setAlarmClock`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) is the only acceptable solution if you *really* need to trigger every 30 minutes. This will probably negate all doze mode energy savings...

BTW: it seems like you can see alarms with `adb shell dumpsys alarm`.

---

Possibility: use [Firebase JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android#user-content-firebase-jobdispatcher-)

> The Firebase JobDispatcher is a library for scheduling background jobs in your Android app. It provides a JobScheduler-compatible API that works on all recent versions of Android (API level 14+) that have Google Play services installed.

Comment: Yeah i have been using the adb shell to set the device to doze and monitor the alarms, however through intensive testing there was an average of 49/50 accuracy with 1 dropped/delayed alarm..... I would cope with the alarm icon being visible all the time, but dropping an alarm is catastrophic.
I don't know if people noticed such issue or was it just my device acting weird.

Comment: Have you considered using [Firebase JobScheduler](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android#user-content-firebase-jobdispatcher-)? It uses Google play and is considered to be on time.

Comment: No, I didn't. But doesn't it build on top of JobScheduler which AlarmManager is part of it?

Comment: It implements the same interface. Somewhere it was said that it allowed users to accurately schedule alarms, as Google can block evil stuff. See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/issues/187.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem as you, and searches a long time for an solution. But I doesn't find a general solution.

A solution for Samsung devices is available:
[Android AlarmManager not working on some devices when the app is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739669/android-alarmmanager-not-working-on-some-devices-when-the-app-is-closed?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The first answer works not, but the second one :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried add your app to the battery optimisation whitelist? As some news pointed out ([link](https://www.theverge.com/2018/7/25/17614014/vlc-blacklisting-recent-huawei-devices-negative-app-reviews)), Huawei has some special battery management.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to show a notification each time the timer fires, then you can use a backend server to send a **data notification** to Android users.

You need to save the FCM tokens of Android clients in your backend server, and the server will be responsible for pushing notifications to those clients.

I know It's a bit complicated for just only showing a notification, but that's who the Android system works!