# Issue in Alarm Manager setRepeat

Tags: android

I need to repeat my Alarm manager every minute. So i wrote the code like

```
  val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)

    val triggerAt = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val oneMinute = (60 * 1000).toLong()

    val alarmMgr = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    val intent = Intent(this, BootCompleteReceiver::class.java)
    val alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0)
    alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent)


    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000 * 60,
            1000 * 60, alarmIntent)
```

But sometimes it's repeating within a minute.

Please help me!

Comment: If you are experiencing accuracy issues, then it is expected. You will experience much worse accuracy if the device enters doze mode. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45079300/android-alarm-manager-setexactandallowwhileidle-not-working-in-android-7-0-nou

Comment: @Mena did you find any solution?

Comment: No, I don't think there is one. Maybe if u gain root access to the device, you might override some android restrictions. But even then, in your case, i doubt it would get you an accurate alarm to the second, so you would have to expect alarms a couple of seconds earlier or later.

Comment: @Mena seconds doesn't matter for me. But the class is calling two to three times within a minute. Not every time, only some times i am facing the issue.

Comment: Does this happen while the the app is in the foreground? Which Android version does your device have?

Comment: @Mena yes. Oreo