# Alarm Manager is not triggering on some devices?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I am setting `AlarmManager` for scheduling local notification. I have tried many different solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739669/android-alarmmanager-not-working-on-some-devices-when-the-app-is-closed), but all in vain.
That answer suggest me to use `setExact()` and `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()`
methods for different version of apis code sample below:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            triggerTime, intent);
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime, intent);
} else {
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime, intent);
}
```

I am checking the device alarm with command `adb shell dumpsys alarm`. Alarms are there, but not triggering.

```
Batch{365d942c num=2 start=132037642 end=132037642}:


 RTC_WAKEUP #1: Alarm{2f05aef5 type 0 when 1506076080000 com.mominapp.mominapp PRAYER_TIME_NOTIFICATION_ACTION}
    tag=*walarm*:PRAYER_TIME_NOTIFICATION_ACTION
    type=0 whenElapsed=+35m18s677ms when=2017-09-22 15:28:00
    window=0 repeatInterval=0 count=0
    operation=PendingIntent{738548a: PendingIntentRecord{297a3afb com.mominapp.mominapp broadcastIntent}}
```

This shows that **my application has an alarm scheduled at 15:28**  but it is not triggered by any mean. I am facing this problem specially for **OPPO** and **Samsung** **Devices**.

Any help will be appreciated. Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure auto-restart mode and background data turned on?

Also in oppo device make sure

SETTING - BATTERY - OTHERS - choose the app that you want to keep notification - turn off FREEZE BACKGROUND APPS

SETTING - BATTERY Low Power Mode must be OFF

Comment: Some app is working on same device with Freeze mode and power saving mode thats why my client is stuck with this.