# Android alarm not firing when phone is in sleep/doze mode

Tags: android, alarm, wakelock

I know that Wakelocks are a thing. I use it in my code, however, I don't think it works. I use a TimePicker which the user can choose a time, and I later set a alarm for that time like this:

```
receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                        @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
                        {
                            // Code here when time is hit...
                        }
                    };

                    _thisContext.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("com.basse.bla.blabla"));
                    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(_thisContext, 0, new Intent("com.basse.bla.blabla, 0);

                    // Check if chosen time is the next day
                    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                    if (calendar.before(now)) {
                        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
                    }

                    // Set an alarm exact when the time is hit
                    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pintent);
                    
                    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) _thisContext.getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
                    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "blabla:wakelog");
                    wakelock.aquire();
```

**The important thing is that when OnReceive fires, I want to start a foreground service.** I've read that AlarmManager aquires a wakelock? Let's say that the time is 3:24 PM. I choose with the TimePicker that I want the "alarm" to fire at 6:48 PM.

The problem is that if I leave my phone between that timeperiod, the phone goes to sleep/doze mode. I know that I can request the user to turn off battery optimizations, but many users find that difficult. How can I keep the alarm "running" in the background, so that it fires at the right time?

Comment: See the answers for this https://stackoverflow.com/q/39739669/1133011, but it seems that device manufactures aren't allowing alarms to be fired when battery saving or optimisations are turned on and besides you requesting the user to turn off power saving for you app it doesn't seem like it can be done progamatically.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp Sort of, but I don't know yet. Thanks for posting though!